# django left join

Tags: django, left-join

I have a bit of a left join issue.. I have the following models

```
class CommandInfo(models.Model):
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group = models.ForeignKey(ApplicationGroup, blank=True, default=0)
    host = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ip = models.IPAddressField(db_index=True)
    about = models.TextField()
    firstTS = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    lastTS = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    processed = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length=1, default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.host
```

I need to grab all the server instances and left join the CommandInfo to it if there is one.

Right now I'm doing it in raw sql

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT host,ts,count as host FROM servers_server LEFT JOIN cmds_commandinfo ON server_id=servers_server.id")
servers = cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code like the following:

```
s = Server.objects.get(id=1)
cmdinfo = s.commandinfo_set.all()
```

Which would return a list of all CommandInfo objects that have `s` set as the foreign key.

You can get more info at the Django docs, "[Following Relationships Backward](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)".

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Django ORM needs the left join field name to be explicitly name with select_related().

This is just off the top of my head so you'll probably need to tweak it, but try something like:

```
s = Server.objects.select_related('commandinfo_set')
```

Comment: `.select_related` doesn't work on backward relationships, so this wouldn't work. It only works on `ForeignKey` and `OneToOneField` fields in the model on which the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
commands_by_server_id = defaultdict(list)
for c in CommandInfo.objects.select_related('server'):
  commands_by_server_id[c.server.id].append(c)

servers = Server.objects.all()
for s in servers:
  s.commands = commands_by_server_id.get(s.id, [])
```

Please note that you need to get the servers list due you can servers without CommandInfo