# django double left join + django rest framework serializers

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have these models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Group(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ItemGroup(models.Model):
   item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Means an item can be in multiple groups.

I want to query **all** items, and for each item return his groups as a nested list (or an empty list if the item does not appear in a group).

This is what I would do with sql:

```
SELECT item.id, item.name, group.name
FROM items
LEFT JOIN item_group ON item.id = item_group.id
LEFT JOIN group ON group.id = item_group.group_id
```

(I might add an `ORDER BY` too, for paging, but nevermind for now).

This query would give me every item X number of groups the item is connected too, and at least one row for an item that does not appear in any group (with group set to null).
Then, I'll need to convert it to a nested list manually.

The question:
1. How to do the same joins with django ORM?  This is the closest question I've found:  [django left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769769/django-left-join)
But the answer isn't actually a left join, but a `prefetch_related`, which I want to avoid.
2. If I would create a nested `dict` of models like this:
 `{item: [list of groups for the item]}` . Is there a way to feed that to django rest framework serializers?   cause it seems that ModelSerializer can only work with querysets.

Answer (score 1):

1) What you want to do is counter to how Django works and will result in more pain than it's worth. I'd recommend doing the `prefetch_related` as suggested. You may also want to explore the following. Here are the docs on [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships).

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Group(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   items = models.ManyToManyField(Group, through='ItemGroup')

class ItemGroup(models.Model):
   item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

2) Take a look into [`ListField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield). I think it should help you accomplish what you want there.